# Observer pattern or helper class? (php)

Tags: php, observer-pattern

lets imagine our forum system, I want to post a comment

```
class Thread
{
    public function post ($userId, $threadId, $comment)
    {
        SQL INSERT INTO table $userId, $threadId, $comment
        // sending emails
        // public on a notice-wall
    }
}
```

I dont want hardcode the `sending emails` and `public on a notice-wall` codes, because even it would only be two method call, it hurts the SRP principle. I can see two ways:

using a helper:

```
public function post ($userId, $threadId, $comment)
{
    SQL INSERT INTO table $userId, $threadId, $comment
    ForumHelper::sendEmailsAndPublicOnNoticeWall ($userId, $threadId, $comment);
}
```

but they say its a sign of bad practice.
2nd, I could use Observer Pattern. What to use then?

Comment: You are already breaking SRP in your pseudo-code by binding it to storage-specific stuff (that is, SQL). What if storage changes? Or if it's version/format changes? That must be a work for data mappers model layer. Regarding question - use a chain of processing where you will register whatever actions are needed to perform for your method(s). Then you will be able to configure it and isolate entity logic from event processing logic + in same time, avoid non-obvious "triggering" stuff (imagine - if you have 10+ events in "observing" - how painful will be to get what's happening in that magic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Thread
{
    // ideally make this protected and use setters / getters,
    // you could also consider to use an array of listeners
    // to have multiple listeners
    public $listener = NULL; 

    public function postComment($userId, $threadId, $comment)
    {
        // SQL INSERT INTO table $userId, $threadId, $comment
        // let's assume that you have a $post object with the
        // informations regarding your post

        $this->_notifyOfCommentPost($postedComment);
    }

    protected function _notifyOfCommentPost($postedComment) {
        if (!isset($this->listener)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->listener->onPostCommented($postedComment);
    }
}
```

This structure enables you to then define a listener:

```
class OnCommentPostedListener {
    public function onCommentPosted($postedComment) {
        ForumHelper::sendEmailsForComment($postedComment);
        ForumHelper::sendPublicOnNoticeWallForComment($postedComment);
    }
}

$thread->listener = new OnCommentPostedListener();
```

Here the behavior about what to do when a comment is posted is not in the Thread class managing your thread. Your model (how you store information) doesn't know about your business logic (sending emails and posting notifications) it just notifies the outside world (the Observable Pattern) when it does an operation.

The benefit of this is that adding a new behavior after a new comment is posted do not require to alter your Thread class.